# How can hibernate access a private field?

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, field, private

How can hibernate can access a private field/method of a java class , for example to set the @Id ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like Crippledsmurf says, it uses reflection.  See [Reflection: Breaking all the Rules](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t16714.html) and [Hibernate: Preserving an Object's Contract](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91937279.html#).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Test {
   private final int value;
   Test(int value) { this.value = value; }
   public String toString() { return "" + value; }
}

public class Main {
   public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
       Test test = new Test(12345);
       System.out.println("test= "+test);

       Field value = Test.class.getDeclaredField("value");
       value.setAccessible(true);
       System.out.println("test.value= "+value.get(test));
       value.set(test, 99999);
       System.out.println("test= "+test);
       System.out.println("test.value= "+value.get(test));
   }
}
```

prints

```
test= 12345
test.value= 12345
test= 99999
test.value= 99999
```

Answer (score 3):

At a guess I would say that this is done by reflecting on the target type and setting the fields directly using reflection

I am not a java programmer but I believe java has reflection support similar to that of .NET which I do use