# Do I have to have the word get and set in my Java class using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Most examples I've seen are like [this](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-hello-world-program-saving-an-objcet/),

```
private int productId;
private String proName;
private double price;

public void **set**ProductId(int productId)
{
    this.productId = productId;
}
public int **get**ProductId()
{
    return productId;
}

public void setProName(String proName)
{
    this.proName = proName;
}
public String getProName()
{
    return proName;
}

public void setPrice(double price)
{
    this.price = price;
}
public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
```

Is this naming convention required when using Hibernate?

Comment: I don't think it is as long as you put the annotation on the field name.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: This is in the Javabean specification, so I would use it even if it wasn't needed, since other libraries besides Hibernate would expect it to be according to standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This name convention was originally introduced by [Java Beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean). The uniform naming convention of properties (`getXXX` and `setXXX`) allowed runtime discovery (and access) of properties of the java beans for frameworks.
Since Hibernate can access the private fields using reflection, as it is explained in [How can hibernate access a private field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113359/how-can-hibernate-access-a-private-field), it is not neccessary to follow this naming convention, but it is a good practice.

Comment: But ;) When you make your fields public, the setter and getters are not necessary any more. Then you lose the possibility to do something with the data in the getter and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Hibernate 3.6 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html):

> Hibernate works best if these classes follow some simple rules, also known as the Plain Old Java Object (POJO) programming model. However, none of these rules are hard requirements. Indeed, Hibernate assumes very little about the nature of your persistent objects. You can express a domain model in other ways (using trees of java.util.Map instances, for example).